# getChildHtml(‘media’) returning blank in magento

Tags: magento

Till yesterday all was fine, all of sudden `<?php getChildHtml(‘media’) ?>` is not returning any html just blank in `view.phtml`.

I checked `catalog.xml` file:

```
html_entities('<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
<block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml" />
</block>
</reference>');
```

Please help where else I need to check to make it run again.

Comment: *Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow.* To help us answer your question, we'll need a bit more detail. Perhaps sharing snippets of your `catalog.xml` configuration file and the part of your `view.phtml` file that triggers `getChildHtml('media')` - without that, there's not much we can do :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [getChildHtml(‘media’) returning blank in view.phtml magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763228/getchildhtml-media-returning-blank-in-view-phtml-magento)