# getChildHtml(‘media’) returning blank in view.phtml magento

Tags: image, magento, product

Till yesterday all was fine, all of sudden`<?php  getChildHtml(‘media’) ?>` is not returning any html just blank in `view.phtml.`
I checked catalog.xml file:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
<block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml" />
</block>
</reference>
```

Where else I need to check to make it run again?

Answer (score 0):

Praveen,Please try this

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('media') ?>
```

Instead of

`<?php  getChildHtml(‘media’) ?`>

**as per as your code $this missing**

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for your help but I used <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('media') ?> in view.phtml file but unfortunately its not worked.